# A Really Strong reason For a War - Fantasy extra terrestrial story

Tags: warfare, races

In my fantasy story, there is a very important flashback: centuries back, there were 3 humanoid races - always in war with each other. The third race is more evil, more powerful(both physically & technically) than the other two. The first and second race formed an alliance and they finally defeated the third race. A few members of the third race escaped to another planet (they have high-tech), all others of the third race were killed.

In the present day, the remaining countries of the first and second race developed a lot on their own means and the third race is returning to the planet to avenge the defeat from centuries ago.

I hope it is possible that such a highly developed country is defeated by two other countries which are very poorly developed, for example if one of the races has ability to control nature - can make earthquake, tsunami etc.

My question is why should the three countries fall in war in the first place? I need a strong reason for keeping them in war and which must be strong enough to make the refugees of third race to return after centuries to pay the debt.

Comment: Isn't that the story of World of Warcraft or original Heroes of Might and Magic? inHoMM IV I think there was supposed to be explained that the "fantasy" is actual technology.

Comment: Both the Roman Empire and the Persians wanted Mesopotamia. The Roman-Persian wars began in the 1st century BCE and last for 8 centuries, when they stopped because both empires were conquered by the Muslim Arabs. France wanted to expand east and the Germanies wanted to expand west, and the Franco-German wars began somewhere around the 11th century and continued for nine centuries -- they are currently at peace because members of the E.U., but who knows for how long? For some strange reason, for the last 24 centuries everybody who had an empire wanted to conquer Afghanistan... (And failed.)

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY in the world of MM (HoMM being part of it), it has always been the case that everything stems from a highly technological races. The  things we see in MM (and HoMM), is colonies which were cut off and eventually forgot their origins. I'm not entirely sure on what direction newer titles (HoMM 5+) have taken but MM 1-9 and HoMM 1-4 were definitely there. In MM7 you even visit a space ship and use "anceient weapons"...which are laser pistols.

Comment: Anyway, as for OP's question - do you *really* need a reason? There have been wars fought for the most trivial of reasons throughout history. And once in a war people don't usually go "Wait, this is a stupid reason to war over" but instead tend to put even more effort into hating the enemy. If a war lasts, 10 years or so, it's starts being pretty irrelevant *what* the actual war is about. There might even be different accounts for the basis.

Comment: With that said, the *stated* reason for war is rarely the *actual* reason. Wars are usually fought for power and control of something. Be that a resource, territory or something else. Religion is a very convenient excuse for getting even more people and territory. WW1 is hardly *just* the result of a single guy assassinating another one. If it wasn't the assassination, it'd have been something else that made the tension boil over into war.

Comment: hmm.....theres many factor reason for war and most of them doesnt need rational reason too (theres many stupid reason that result in each country war from pig crossing border to claiming a single bucket). but generally its all about "difference" either race, group, or believe, etc that breed conflict like from fear, hatred or revenge, and greed . and the rest is circumstance of need like food or land.

Comment: WWI - WWII story works. The third developed nation is like Germany: it lacked resources, went to fight for them, but was overwhelmed by sheer numbers of its enemies. In exile, they drew until they ran out of resources, and memories of defeat have been replaced by stories of treachery and pride in new accomplishments. So now they are ready to undo historic injustice. The remaining two countries can still go to war since common enemy is gone, and land/resources are finite.

Comment: By war, do we mean continuous fighting (battle after battle, with a variable no-man's land) or are we saying that the sides in question have at best occasional ceasefire agreements that they keep violating? Do both sides put economic sanctions on each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible reasons, but among the strongest is that your third race (more powerful and evil than the others) was about to conquer and in the consequence likely enslave or completely exterminate the other two races. Avoiding **slavery** and the **destruction of their homelands and culture** or even sheer **genocide** will be very strong incentives for your two less developed races to fight at any cost and with all means aginst the third one.

As for a reason for coming back, the generations coming after original fugitives and exiles of the third race wish to return to their homelands from which they only ever heard stories how their noble ancestors were injustly and burtally driven out by savages with time altering the stories much to battle heroics and despicable deeds of the first and second race. Given that they live on a different planet/world/plane, there is no actual chance to check, if 'the stories are true', before the full army marching to conquest arrives, as scouting will be just too dangerous for the scouts and in giving up the element of surprise or simply takes up too much time.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to have a reason. For example, the Punic wars extended to over 100 years, and in the later stages, the original cause is probably not well known to the people anyway.

Comment: I hate to get political, but the 'war on terror' has in large part been sponsored by many weapons manufacturers. The bomb-market is a great reason to keep a war going.

Answer (score 0):

You can have every reason to start any endless war, and the most rational way is just as irrational as any. The best idea to start a war is to have it relate to something necessary to survival such as habitable space, air to breathe, food resources, threat to your tradition, opposition of ideals, right to life, anything.

Given your premise, most likely its the assimilative extermination pact forged between the two allies, which they carried out through a targeted bioweapon or virus or plague or whatever, designed to turn the third species into any of the two lesser species, tainting their evil-centered purity and power.

Maybe the thought of becoming a lesser species drove most of them disgusted by themselves, committing suicide and consequently, genocide on their own. People of the third species who turned, asked to be killed right away, because they would rather die than become, let alone work with, even one of those disgusting creatures. As such, they killed everyone with the potential markers that can be infected and left.

In that other planet however, they refined their genetic purity, engineering their very blood as poison to any other species, and they're coming back to reclaim what's "rightfully theirs".